# Excel Copy and Paste data into Word - keeping bold and underline

Tags: excel, ms-word

I am trying to cut and paste Excel data into a Word document. The data is only in 1 column, and there are several cells that have bolding and underlining in them.

I would like to be able to copy and paste the data into a word, keeping the bold and underlining.

I have tried everything I can think of, but I don't see any way to keep the formatting in word.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Eric

Answer (score 0):

Copy the table to Word as usual. Then go to Table Tools -> Layout -> Convert to Text and keep the formatting.

[Convert to text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkCJf.png)

Comment: Actually, no.  I should have been more clear.  I don't want the excel cells in the word document, just the values in the cells (including the text formatting).

Comment: I see, then you can try the edit method above. Would that help?